# How to label vertex/line within mesh

Tags: export, vertices

I'm exporting to my own format, and there's a few special vertices (not necessarily part of any triangles) but should move with the other vertices when the bones are posed and otherwise behave as part of the mesh. For example a few such vertices around the palm of the hand would keep track of where held items would be anchored to the mesh, or even a few unattached points within the torso representing the location of various internal organs. Probably one between the eyes where the camera is mounted, or for testing what is within it's field of vision. That sort of thing.

My problem is 1) how to uniquely identify certain vertices, preferably with a string of text, and 2) how to identify these vertices within the python export script.

The ability to name lines or triangles would be even better, but naming vertices would be sufficient.

The only method I can think of is adding specially named bones and treating them as vertices in the export script.

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertices can be added to named groups. This information is available to the export script.